# How to wait for data in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

For example I have 2 components. In 1st I do async call on server and after dispatch action to put response in to redux store. In 2nd component I want to wait for the response come to store and after do some work.

1st component looks like

```
const response = await api.call(); // async call on server
dispatch(putToTheStore(response)); // put data to the store
```

2nd component looks like

```
await props.response; // here i want to wait data come to store

// and after it actually come to the store, do some work
```

Is it possible  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you connect your second component to the store using `react-redux`'s `connect` function, you don't need to do anything explicit to update the component. The data you added to the store will simply be available to the component as a `prop`.

If you need to (synchronously) do some work on the loaded data, e.g. apply a filter, or do some sorting, I would recommend doing this directly in the `mapStateToProps` function, as this function is called automatically each time the store updates to calculate the new `props` for your component.

If you need to do some additional work in the second component, i.e. load more data based on the previous asynchronous call, you would need to implement the [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) function.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps - forgot about this